# Differences between deep and shallow bindings for static scoping

Tags: programming-languages, binding, pascal

I am self-learning Michael L. Scott's Programming Language Pragmatics. [The following quote](https://books.google.com/books?id=GBISkhhrHh8C&lpg=PA154&dq=deep%20binding%20in%20pascal&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q=deep%20binding%20in%20pascal&f=false) explains how deep binding and shallow binding are different in the presence of static scoping:

> ```
> program binding_example(input, output);
>
> procedure A(I : integer; procedure P);
>
>     procedure B;
>     begin
>         writeln(I);
>     end;
>
> begin (* A *)
>     if I > 1 then
>         P
>     else
>         A(2, B);
> end;
>
> procedure C; begin end;
>
> begin (* main *)
>     A(1, C);
> end.
> ```
>
> Figure 3.15 contains a Pascal program that illustrates the impact of
>   **deep binding** rules in the presence of **static scoping**.  When B is called via formal parameter P, two instances of I exist. Because
>   the closure for P was created in the initial invocation of A, B uses
>   that invocation’s instance of I in its writeln statement, and the
>   output is a 1.
>
> With **shallow binding** it would print a 2.

1. Firstly I am new to Pascal. Is it correct that in the program, there
   are four separate parts:

   - the definition of procedure `A`, which only defines procedure `B`
   - a block named `A`
   - the definition of procedure `C`
   - a block named `main`?

   When executing the program,

   - is the block `main` first executed and then the block `A`?
   - Why does it say that "When B is called via formal parameter P, two instances of I exist"?
2. Now to understand the difference between deep and shallow bindings
   in the presence of static scoping

   - Why in the presence of static scoping and deep binding, does the program print `1`?
   - Why in the presence of static scoping and shallow binding, does the program print `2`?

Thanks.

Comment: You're using the term "static binding" everywhere in your question, but the quoted passage never mentions static binding; it mentions "static scoping."

Comment: What other languages do you know? Maybe the problem would be clearer if the code were to be translated from Pascal to another language such as JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly I am new to Pascal. Is it correct that in the program, there are four separate parts...

The general construct is that of an entity with (a) nested definitions, and, (b) one body.

So, `A` & `C` are nested within (program) `binding_example`, and, `B` is nested within (procedure) `A`.

> When executing the program,
>   is the block main first executed and then the block A?

Sort of, but not exactly.  Flow of control is initially transferred to the first line of the program body.  Since that line of code invokes `A`, the program body is suspended, a copy of `A` is activated with the relevant parameters from the program body statement, and flow of control is transferred to the first line of `A`s body and with that new activation.

> Why does it say that "When B is called via formal parameter P, two instances of I exist"?

Because `A` is a recursive function.  It invokes itself as you can see in `A`'s body.  Thus, if you follow the logic and flow of control, there will be two copies of `A` activated at one point in the execution of the program.  Since `A` defines `I`, if there are two `A`s, then there are two `I`s.

First, the bindings only work one way here.  The mention of shallow bindings, in this example, are only hypothetical.

Which is to say that the author is making the point that if the language worked differently, well, it would work differently...

(Personally, I'm not a big fan of hypothetical alternatives as tutorial material -- I find them often poorly thought through.)

As the author is not fully explaining how this hypothetical and different language would work, we are best just taking author's point that deep bindings end up choosing the first activation of `A`, since that is the environment that conjures the actual parameter `B`.

> Why in the presence of static scoping and deep binding, does the program print 1?

Because when `A` is first activated, that in some sense, creates a `B` that can now be referenced (without an `A` we don't have a `B` to use).  Now, `A` chooses to reference its `B`, and, that `B` knows about its `A`, and hence about `A`'s `I`, which holds, `1`, after all.  Now `A` is recursively invoked, which creates a second activation of `A`, having its own `I`, whose value is `2`.  Now that second `A` invokes `P`, which is the first `A`s `B`, so `1` is printed.

> Why in the presence of static scoping and shallow binding, does the program print 2?

As I mentioned, this is just a hypothetical case, and I don't consider it fully baked because the text of the procedures would not make sense as such and would also have to change to satisfy this hypothetical pascal that had instead shallow bindings.

Comment: Thanks. 1. What is the relation betw procedure `A` and the part `begin (* A *) ... end`?  2. What do `*` and `(* A *)` mean? 3. Does `(* main *)` indicate that   `begin (* main *) ... end` is the program's body?

Comment: 1. That is the body of `A`.  2. These `(* ...*)` are comments in Pascal, of course.  It is common practise that because the body for the program (or procedure) is often separated from its initial declaration (by all those other nested definitions), that when it finally appears, it is thusly commented.  (And some do it all the time even for small texts.)  Sometimes the `end;` is similarly commented.  3. Yes.

Comment: How is the end of a procedure specified in Pascal? I thought the body of procedure `A` ends after the definition of `B`, and ` begin (* A *) ... end` is outside the definition of procedure `A`.

Comment: that `begin ... end` is part of the definition of something, in particular, that is the body part, and the body comes last, so its `end;` means the procedure (or program) is finally over.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that if replace static scoping with dynamic scoping in the case of recursion,  the same thing can be said about deep and shallow bindings? In other words, in the case of recursion, static and dynamic binding doesn't matter, as much as deep  and shallow bindings are concerned?

Comment: I haven't studied dynamic scoping; it seems to me like a very confusing approach.  Here's an interesting, fairly recent post about it.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/331543/63202

Comment: In the example, do the two calls to procedure A during recursion have different instances of procedure B, or the same instance of B?

Comment: There are effectively different instances of a `B` available, each closing over (a different `A`'s) `I`.  Note at any point in the code, `A` only has direct access to one of those `B`s, which is the one associated with itself.  However, by using a function pointer from within an `A`, that `B` closing over that `A`'s `I` can be passed around and used in some other context.

Comment: @Tim, When a `B` function pointer is conjured within the activated `A`, that since `B` closes over `A`'s `I`, a reference to both the code for `B` and some notion of a reference to the activated of `A` (or at least to the activated `A`'s `I`) is captured by the function pointer as environmental context for later use during the function pointers execution.